# Android More menu text is not readable (black text on black background?)

Tags: java, android, menu, colors

I have a menu in my Android app that holds more than 6 items (7 items), and therefore Android automatically adds a 'More' item as the last item. When I click on 'More' item I get a new menu that holds my 6th and 7th items. But, the text is not visible.

The image is from my emulator, Android 2.3.3, but same appears on my physical phones too, Sony Ericsson X10i and Samsung Galaxy S3.

This is how the theme is set in styles.xml:

```
<style name="SespActivityTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateHidden</item>
</style>
```

I have tried to change the theme of the app to both Light and Dark theme, but no result. I have tried to google this, without finding anyone with the same problem. 
Other from this style I haven't tried to change any colors of text or icons.

I get same kind of error in the menu that appeasrs if I long press on a text box, but then it is all white instead of black:

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Here are screenshots:http://imghost.me/images/2013/01/18/XQZGx.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! The following lines makes this strange error:

```
<item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
```

I cannot explain why, but if I remove this line from my style and place it in all activity XMLs then I can read the text again.